# js-ethereum-cryptography secp256k1 signature difficulties

Tags: public-key, signature

I'm currently undertaking a course on Blockchain cryptography.  And our first project is to transfer tokens from one wallet to another using client / server application.  All mock of course.

This project is using the prescribed https://www.npmjs.com/package/ethereum-cryptography

The theory is this as I understand it:

**Client side**

- generate public and private key
- Create what I call an `action` object - `{operation: "transfer", from (public key), to (public key), amount}`
- Hash the action
- Sign the hash with private key to create a signature
- Post the `{action, signature}` to the server

---

**Server side**

- Verify the action using the signature and public key
- Perform the transfer between wallets (if valid)

I'm pretty sure that this is correct.

Now what I had to do required quite a bit of investigation and work arounds and it just feels like it should have been simpler.  I'd like to know if there is a better way.  Here is what I had to do:

**Client side**

- Client side - generate public and private key
- Create what I call an `action` - `{operation: "transfer", from (public key), to (public key), amount}`
- Hash the action with `keccak256(utf8ToBytes(JSON.stringify(action)))`
- Sign the hash with private key to create a Signature using `secp256k1.sign(actionHash, privateKey)`
- **work around ->** Because the returned Signature contains `bigint`s (which seemingly don't serialize), I had to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-bigint to stringify it
- Post the `{action, signature}` to the server

---

**Server side**

- **work around ->** Use `json-bigint` with `{ useNativeBigInt: true }` option to parse the signature (for `BigInt(..)` in the next step)
- Whoops, I missed a detail previously.  The (typed) signature of `verify` is:

```
    verify: (signature: Hex | {
        r: bigint;
        s: bigint;
    }, msgHash: Hex, publicKey: Hex, opts?: import("./abstract/weierstrass.js").VerOpts | undefined) => boolean;
```

and as I discuss below, I couldn't get the Hex version of `signature` to work and despite it just seeming to take a `{r: bigInt, s: bigInt}`, verify complained that I need to pass a Signature object.

- **work around ->** Recreate a Signature object, but as far as I could tell there is none exported from https://www.npmjs.com/package/ethereum-cryptography to use so I needed to recreate the shape and use that with:

```
class Signature {
    constructor({r, s, recovery}) {
        // const {r, s, recovery} = SigLikeObj;
        this.r = BigInt(r);
        this.s = BigInt(s);
        this.recovery = recovery;
    }
}
```

- Verify it with `secp256k1.verify(signatureFixed, actionHash, publicKey)`
- Perform transfer

The `json-bigint` requirement is a detail, but the need to create a `class Signature` seems wrong.

I saw that the `signature` in `verify()` can be a Hex though I couldn't see a way to create this.

I tried this on the Server:

```
    const signatureObj = JSONbig.parse(signatureJson);
    const signatureHex = toHex(new Uint8Array(signatureObj))
    const isValid = secp256k1.verify(signatureHex, actionHash, publicKey);
```

But verification fails this way.

Am I missing something - is there an easier way to handle the `class Signature` or to make a Hex out of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doh!  I updated the question with more detail of the error and then that action highlighted that I completely missed something so obvious.

I just needed to do this for the signature problem:

```
    const signatureObj = JSONbig.parse(signatureJson);
    const signatureObj2 = { r: signatureObj.r, s: signatureObj.s }
    const isValid = secp256k1.verify(signatureObj2, actionHash, publicKey);
```

I must admit I've solved a lot of issues by trying to explain the problem on StackExchange.  Most often I work it out before posting the question.  Oh well, I hope I've helped others.